# Python: time shifting a song (bpm)

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that allows me to time shift music with python in real time. This is exactly what I want to do: http://onlinetonegenerator.com/time-stretcher.html

and a python example: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YT-zAX3S850

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project that seems to do what you have in mind:

http://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/03/29/soundstretching-and-pitch-shifting-in-python/